# Creating economics graphs with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

For writing my economics papers I need to create graphs that show the intuition of an underlying process. A simple example would be the graph linked at the bottom. Note the dashed lines that emphasize a point on the graph.

How would I replicate this graph in ggplot, with

- both vertical and horizontal dashed lines,
- the round intercepting dot where the dashed lines meet
- Q and NIR labels at the axes?

To give an example of a graph:

```
x <- c(10:100)
y <- 1/x
data <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

Let's say I want to indicate the point (25, 0.04) as done in the example graph. How would I do that?

[economics graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpoka.jpg)

Comment: Please supply sample data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for reference.

Comment: data for these graphs I usually just make up, because it is not about data, just intuition

Comment: so say 
x <- c(10:100), y <- 1/x, data <- data.frame(x, y), ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: What have you tried so far? Its imperative to show a minimum effort in the direction of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a subset of data -- i.e. your 2 desired points to `geom_point`, here I use c(25,50)

Use `geom_segment` to create dashed lines to the subsetted points

Use `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` to create axis labels

Use `theme` to change plot theme elements

```
# Create geom_point and geom_segments
gg1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(lwd=2) +
  geom_point(data=data[data$x %in% c(25, 50),], aes(x, y), pch=16, size=5) +
  geom_segment(data=data[data$x %in% c(25, 50),], aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=y), lty=2, lwd=1) +
  geom_segment(data=data[data$x %in% c(25, 50),], aes(x=0, xend=x, y=y, yend=y), lty=2, lwd=1)

gg1

# Define new labels
x_label <- NA
x_label[! x %in% c(25, 50)] <- ""
x_label[x %in% c(25, 50)] <- c("Q", "Q1")
y_label <- NA
y_label[! x %in% c(25, 50)] <- ""
y_label[x %in% c(25, 50)] <- c("NIR", "NIR1")

gg2 <- gg1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks=x, labels=x_label) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=y, labels=y_label)

gg2


# Add axis labels, change theme elements, remove ticks and grid lines
gg3 <- gg2 + xlab("Quantity of Investment") +
ylab("Norminal Interest Rate") +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_text(size=16),
  axis.text = element_text(size=14)) 

gg3
```

[image]